# variable values not passing into function?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a php file that sends data to a mysql database. when i try to send the data get this:

> ERROR! EMPTY RESULTINSERT INTO email
>   (First, Last, Full, Email,
>   CountryCoude, Phone, Company, Serial)
>   VALUES ('','','
>   ','benespitz@gmail.com',,,'Webscan,
>   Inc.','TEST
>   mySQL')BenSpitzbenespitz@gmail.com+1303-459-4521Webscan,
>   Inc.TEST mySQL

as you can see from the output, the variables i put into my insert function are not empty but the values being sent in the query are. why is this?

non-confidential part of the php file:

```
insert($firstname,$lastname,$email,$countrycode,$phonenumber,$companyname,$serialnumber);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTICT * FROM email");
if (empty($result)) {
    echo "ERROR! EMPTY RESULT";
}
else {
    print_r($result);
}
echo "INSERT INTO email (First, Last, Full, Email, CountryCoude, Phone, Company, Serial)
    VALUES ('".$first."','".$last."','".$first." ".$last."','".$email."',".$code.",".$phone.",'".$company."','".$serial."')";
echo $firstname.$lastname.$email.$countrycode.$phonenumber.$companyname.$serialnumber;
?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<?php
function insert ($first, $last, $email, $code, $phone, $company, $serial) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO email (First, Last, Full, Email, CountryCoude, Phone, Company, Serial)
    VALUES ('".$first."','".$last."','".$first." ".$last."','".$email."',".$code.",".$phone.",'".$company."','".$serial."')");
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, before doing anything, you should really be escaping your inputs with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, or using prepared statements. Other than the fact that it doesn't work, that's your biggest problem.

Comment: Silly question, but what if you put the insert statement into a string, then echo out that string before you do the actual mysql_query? Find out what's really going in, as what you have looks correct. Also, CountryCoude doesn't look like it's spelled right.

Comment: @Ben7005: Look it up in the manual. You should already be using the manual. Begin now.

Comment: @AndyD273: It's very not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is a PHP feature that checks PHP variables for certain conditions.

It does *not* have knowledge of MySQL libraries and the fact that your `$result` is just a resource handle. (Indeed, `$result` is never "empty"; it's always an object, and it's always a resource handle, even if it's a handle to an empty resultset.)

Instead of this:

```
if (empty($result)) {
    echo "ERROR! EMPTY RESULT";
}
```

write:

```
if (!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    echo "ERROR! EMPTY RESULT";
}
```

Similarly, `print_r($result)` isn't going to do what you think. Look at the documentation for the library you're using, and use its API. There are **loads** of examples out there about how to iterate a resultset that you retrieved via `mysql_query`; I am not going to repeat them here.

---

You also misspelt `DISTINCT`. Add proper error checking/handling to your code.

---

Don't be misled by the red herring of your broken debug output:

```
echo "INSERT INTO email (First, Last, Full, Email, CountryCoude, Phone, Company, Serial)
    VALUES ('".$first."','".$last."','".$first." ".$last."','".$email."',".$code.",".$phone.",'".$company."','".$serial."')";
```

You used the wrong variable names here. You did not make this mistake in the function that *actually* performs the insert. (I don't understand why this debug output isn't *inside* that function, where this sort of mistake would be really obvious and easy to avoid.)

Comment: i tried your code and if (!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    echo "ERROR! EMPTY RESULT";
} does not work, it gives me the error Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home2/rocksoli/public_html/webscan/trucheckupdates/mySQL-test/sql_submit.php on line 43

Comment: @Ben7005: Because you have no error handling, and your query has the error mentioned in my answer, so `$result` is `FALSE` rather than a result resource. Please read the examples in your PHP book; they will be very thorough.

Comment: @Ben7005: BTW please get into the habit of triggering notifications when you direct a message at someone, using the "@name:" syntax.